# Lotus Notes Formula - Generate sequence of numbers

Tags: lotus-notes

I have two lotus notes views where in the first column I need to have a unique identifier that will be a number.
In the first view, I want the number to start from 1 and then increment to, say 15000. In the next view, I need to start the number from 15001 and increment. Is there a way to achieve this using lotus notes formula? Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only formula that allows it is @DocNumber, but you cannot add 15000 to it. I doubt that your approach is the right one. Please write what you really need, not how you think you can achieve it. Let us solve your problem, not your (unsolvable) question...

Comment: Thanks Torsten. Say I have two views each of 5000 documents in it. I want to provide a unique ID to them by numbering them from 1. So, the first view will have IDs 1-5000 and the second will have 5001-10000. How to achieve this using Lotus Notes formula?

Comment: Whats the use case of having sequential numbering ? If you need to create relations between documents use either @unique or the document universal id

Comment: And if your idea is paging, then you're better off using XPages, or just the plain HTML start= and count= URL parameters.  Also, keep in mind that Notes is designed to be distributed and disconnected.  This means that any number of documents can be added and/or deleted offline and then replicated later.

Comment: That was exactly my point: I understand your question, but it is not really what you need. It is what you THINK you need.... Describe the purpose, why you think it is important to have numbers like that, then we can give you the right approach. If you use such a numbering then take care: It depends on other sorted columns in the view, and if no sorted column is given, then it depends on NoteID of documents. And that will CHANGE on every replica of the database, therefor the numbers for given documents will CHANGE.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with a formula in the views. The only way to do it is by adding sequence numbers to the documents, and that has been a topic of discussion by Notes developers for more than 25 years. There are lots of ways to do it, but there is no "best way". Andre Guirard put together [a very complete write-up about this topic](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/sequential-numbering.htm) IBM's Notes AppDev Wiki.

In most cases, though, it's considered better to find some other way to meet your real underlying requirement.